# Google Analytics PHP API return ERROR 101 on localhost

Tags: google-analytics-api

Good day,

I followed this guide : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php

Working as expected online.
But when i try on localhost it return ERROR 101 (HelloAnalytic.php).

Tried to search infos on Google devs but i can't make this working.
I would prefer to do my test on localhost...

Could someone has a tips for me ?

That's the PHP Service API.
My localhost works with easyPHP 14.

Thanks in advance for your answers/advices.

Comment: Set the required permissions of `HelloAnalytic.php` so that it can be executed (i.e. `#chmod 777 /path/to/HelloAnalytic.php`), if you haven't done it yet.

Comment: Tried with Chrome : The error is : ERR_CONNECTION_RESET . chmod set to 0777.

Comment: edited my message, with error 101